# Do modules deployed via Azure IoT Edge runtime require an Azure IoT SDK client?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have a service that's already Dockerized. The service listens on some ports and makes some outbound network calls. At the moment, updating the service requires someone to access the console remotely and manually replace the old container with the latest version.

After reading through the Azure IoT Edge documentation and the SDKs, it's not clear to me if an Azure IoT module MUST include an Azure IoT SDK. I know the Azure IoT SDK is necessary for passing messages, accessing the module twin, and probably more, but I don't need any of that at the moment for this specific use-case.

Can I reuse my existing Docker containers with Azure IoT Edge or would I need to add the Azure IoT SDK (because there's a health check or other internal requirement for the SDK)?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Azure IoT SDK is the recommended way to do messaging, access twin etc. But it is optional.

If you just want the IoT Edge runtime to launch a Docker container that listens on local ports and performs outbound network calls, you can certainly do that. Nothing will get in your way.